# How to fix "Check failed: background_label_id != label (0 vs. 0) Found background label in the dataset" in training SSD?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe, object-detection

I am training SSD model by following the steps specified on the wiki to [train SSD on custom dataset](https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/wiki/Train-SSD-on-custom-dataset). I have around 60k images **with background** as also a label to eliminate false positives. (Please note that **I don't have any image with only background labels** in it.) Created lmdb files for training and testing without any issues. When I initiate the training, I get the following error:

```
    bbox_util.cpp:1066] Check failed: background_label_id != label (0 vs. 0) Found background label in the dataset.

    *** Check failure stack trace: ***
        @     0x7f00cfcef5cd  google::LogMessage::Fail()
        @     0x7f00cfcf1433  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
        @     0x7f00cfcef15b  google::LogMessage::Flush()
        @     0x7f00cfcf1e1e  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
        @     0x7f00d057ed71  caffe::GetGroundTruth<>()
        @     0x7f00d03f5f7e  caffe::MultiBoxLossLayer<>::Forward_cpu()
        @     0x7f00d0541537  caffe::Net<>::ForwardFromTo()
        @     0x7f00d05418a7  caffe::Net<>::Forward()
        @     0x7f00d05db510  caffe::Solver<>::Step()
        @     0x7f00d05dbf9e  caffe::Solver<>::Solve()
        @           0x40bcf4  train()
        @           0x4077c8  main
        @     0x7f00ce486830  __libc_start_main
        @           0x408099  _start
        @              (nil)
```

I searched for the [same issue on git repo](https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=background_label_id+%21%3D+label) but none of the solutions provided worked.

This is the script I am using for training: [train_ssd.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/weiliu89/caffe/ssd/examples/ssd/ssd_pascal.py) 
The file that produces the error: [bbox_util.cpp](https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/blob/ssd/src/caffe/util/bbox_util.cpp#L1066)

Link to source files: [src/caffe](https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd)

**How to initiate the training with labelled backgrounds in data set (to eliminate false positives) without any issues?**

Comment: What do you mean under 'background as also a label'? Do you have explicit bounding boxes for background? And how this should help in eliminating false positives?

Comment: @DmytroPrylipko Yes, I have explicit boxes for background. The model is SSD and SSD samples negatives only from images which have ground truth annotation. So having explicit bounding boxes certainly should help in eliminating false positives.

Answer (score 2):

First, having a class id equals to 0 is not possible in the current Caffe-SSD implementation, since it is reserved for background. Technically, you might use another class id for it, but it will be not the same.

I have worked with SSD a lot and never heard about explicit labeling of background. Moreover, I believe this does not make any sense, as the concept of background is fundamentally different from salient objects (for instance, at non-maximum suppression).

Eliminating false positives is a part of the training objective (reduce false positives, increase true positive rate, reduce false negatives etc.). So just having your model properly trained on target dataset should help you with this.

If your motivation is to sample background samples from images that do not have annotated objects of your class: You might introduce an auxiliary class just to make this happen and then drop it/ignore its detections. However, normally SSD does not have problem with amount of negative samples. Indeed, there is a hyperparam that restricts the negative samples ratio in order not suppress the positive object samples. The default values is 3:1 (neg/pos), but you can make it larger to see whether this helps you with your task.